# jQuery countdown plugin multiple instances not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown, instances

i have problem with my script using jquery.countdown.js plugin, it doesn't sets multiple instances for each element i pass it to,  it always sets the first instance for all, so countdowns are always the same.

link to plugin : http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

```
   $(function(){

     $.each($('.countdown'), function() {
     var _element = '.countdown-'+$(this).attr("id");
     if($(_element).length > 0){
    var _expDate = $(_element).attr('data-expiration').split(',');
    var _datetime = Date(_expDate);
    init_countdown(_element,_datetime);
   }

});      
});

  function init_countdown(_element,_datetime){
    console.log(_element + ", " + _datetime)
    $(_element).countdown({
      until: _datetime,
      format: 'yowdHMS'
    });

  }
```

HTML:

```
<h5 class="muted countdown countdown-1" id="1" data-expiration="2014,10,26,14,10,35"> 2014-10-26 14:10:35</h5>
<h5 class="muted countdown countdown-2" id="2" data-expiration="2014,10,26,16,10,35"> 2014-10-26 16:10:35</h5>
<h5 class="muted countdown countdown-3" id="3" data-expiration="2014,10,26,18,10,35"> 2014-10-26 18:10:35</h5>
```

this is how it outputs

[image]

how can i fix this?

```
console.log() 

.countdown-1, Sun Oct 28 2012 22:10:09 GMT+0100 (CET)


.countdown-2, Sun Oct 28 2012 22:10:09 GMT+0100 (CET)


.countdown-3, Sun Oct 28 2012 22:10:09 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

@Asad example:

[image]

Comment: Can you verify that `console.log(_element + ", " + _datetime)` in `init_countdown` prints the same thing?

Comment: Whats purpose of this test if(_element)??? Do you you want to test if element exists or what?

Comment: if _element is setted cause sometimes id attr is empty

Comment: @ianpgall check i edited question

Comment: @roasted i removed that control if i would like to check if $(this).attr("id"); is empty or not

Comment: This: `'.countdown-'+$(this).attr("id")` is always non falsy. (Truthy?) Your condition is redundant.

Comment: Are you sure that each element has a different "data-expiration" attribute?

Comment: @Asad it could be false sometimes, for that i need to control if not empty/false init else not init ..

Comment: @ianpgall yes that is sure at 200%

Comment: @Asad I agree, but I think they meant to just check for the `id` attribute being empty, but what they had before was redundant - it would need to be changed to do what they want.

Comment: @Ispuk It **always** evaluates to a non empty string, which used as a condition will always be equivalent to true.

Comment: @Asad can you show me somenthing i will try that!

Comment: @Ispuk    if($(_element).length > 0)

Comment: @Ispuk Could you please also post your markup? You could be feeding an invalid date format to the constructor. This would return a Date object representing the current time for all three instances.

Comment: BTW should be: var _datetime = new Date(_expDate);   Isn't it?!

Comment: @Asad html markup on question now

Comment: @roasted using new Date() it prints NaN in counter

Comment: ID must be unique and should'nt strat with number except in html5, but not sure it is your problem here

Comment: @roasted nope sorry my mistake copying and pasting :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date constructor (in the form you are using it) accepts several integer values, not an array. You need to turn each value in the array that results from your split into a integer (using `parseInt`), then pass each argument **individually**, and not as an array.

Try this:

```
var _expDate = $(_element).attr('data-expiration').split(',');
_expDate.forEach(function(v,i,a){a[i]=parseInt(a[i]);});
var _datetime = new Date(_expDate[0],_expDate[1],_expDate[2],_expDate[3],_expDate[4],_expDate[5]);
```

Comment: how to do that sorry? parseInt(what?)

Comment: @Ispuk yes, I just realised I need to pass each element in the array as a separate argument. Hold on.

Comment: tryed now, it makes BANG! :D i mean .. check the question i put new image

Comment: @Ispuk That is because of your format string. Try something simpler, like `'HMS'` instead of `'yowdHMS'`

Comment: i noticed with HMS for example minutes and seconds works well, but not hours, with compact:true, minutes and seconds are ok but not days ... wtf :D

Comment: Hey, I didn't make the library. :P This solves your original problem though.

Comment: nope it doesn't fixes :) cause maybe i'm using the wrong date format :D

Comment: A date object doesn't have a format. Your issue was the fact that an incorrect date object was being passed was being passed for the countdown. That issue has been resolved. As far as formatting the output goes, I have suggested you use `HMS`. If the library is broken, the library is broken.